# populate a class variable with the value of another class variable

Tags: python, json

I am trying to populate my title variable from the contents of chart_title like this:

```
class LineHighChart(object):
    chart_title = ''

    title = {'text':chart_title,
             'x':-20
             }
```

I do this in another by:

```
def weight_graph(request):
    highchart = LineHighChart()

    chart_title = 'my chart title'


    highchart.chart_title = chart_title

    print highchart.__dict__

    return JsonResponse(highchart.__dict__, safe=False)
```

This does not contain the populated title property, but instead prints:

```
{'chart_title': 'joe'}
```

I want it to print:

```
{'title': {'text':'my chart title',
             'x':-20
             }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better way to take advantage of changing instance variables based on set setter values would be to do the following:

```
class LineHighChart(object):
    #title = {'text':' ', 'x':-20}


    def __init__(self, title, subtitle, x_axis_list, y_axis_title, metric, series):

        self.title = {'text': title, 'x':-20}

        self.subtitle =  {
            'text': subtitle,
            'x': -20
        }

        self.xAxis = {
            'categories': x_axis_list
        }

        self.yAxis = {
            'title': {
                'text':y_axis_title
            },
            'plotLines': [{
                'value': 0,
                'width': 1,
                'color': '#808080'
            }]
        }

        self.tooltip = {
            'valueSuffix': metric
        }

        self.legend = {
            'layout': 'vertical',
            'align': 'right',
            'verticalAlign': 'middle',
            'borderWidth': 0
        }

        self.series = series
```

And then call this class like:

```
def weight_graph(request):
    print 'weight graph'
    x_axis_list = ['Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3']
    series = [{
            'name': 'Tokyo',
            'data': [7.0, 1.0, 9.5]
        }, {
            'name': 'New York',
            'data': [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7]
        }]

    highchart = LineHighChart(
                              'my chart',
                              'last seven days',
                              x_axis_list,
                              'Weight',
                              ' lbs',
                              series
                              )

    return JsonResponse(highchart.__dict__, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the title dictionary inside LineHighChart doesn't get automatically updated because you update another property of the object. You could use a setter property if you want to get this behaviour:

```
class LineHighChart(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._chart_title = ''
        self.title = {'text': self._chart_title, 'x':-20}

    @property
    def chart_title(self):
        return self._chart_title

    @chart_title.setter
    def chart_title(self, value):
        self._chart_title = value
        self.title['text'] = value  

highchart = LineHighChart()
chart_title = 'my chart title'
highchart.chart_title = chart_title
print highchart.__dict__
# {'_chart_title': 'my chart title', 'title': {'text': 'my chart title', 'x': -20}}
```

I also changed your class variables(`class.variable` shared by all instances of this class) to instance variables (`self.variable`) so that when you update chart_title in one object it doesn't affect other instances of the same class.

Comment: This way setting `chart_title` for one instance will affect all the instances. I don't think that is desired here, better move the first two declaration inside of `__init__`.

Comment: Oh you are right, didn't notice that he had class level variables. Should be ok now.

Comment: I get the error:  LineHighChart' object has no attribute 'title'

Comment: @Atma, have you made additional changes to the code? I have just tested again my exact code and it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

You defined several class level variables that will not appear in an instance `__dict__`

```
class LineHighChart(object):
    chart_title = ''
    title = {'text':chart_title,
             'x':-20
             }
```

You then defined an instance level variable with the same name as the class variable

```
highchart = LineHighChart()
chart_title = 'my chart title'
highchart.chart_title = chart_title
```

Although the names are the same, these two variables exist in different namespaces.When you json encode the instance level namespace, nothing from the class level is included.

If you want instance level attributes, include them in the class init

```
class LineHighChart(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.chart_title = ''
        self.title = {'text':self.chart_title,
             'x':-20
             }
```

But consider also that `self.title['text']` won't change when a new value is assigned to `self.chart_title`.

Answer (score 0):

As the title talks about class variables ...

```
class LineHighChart(object):
    chart_title = 'Class Variable'

    # using a property getter for the title, to be dynamic
    @property
    def title(self):
        # uses the class variable
        return {'text': LineHighChart.chart_title, 'x': -20}

    def __init__(self):
        # gets initialized and will not be changed
        self.title2 = {'text': self.chart_title, 'x': -20}

def weight_graph(request):
    highchart = LineHighChart()
    lowchart = LineHighChart()

    # setting a NEW object variable
    highchart.chart_title = 'new object variable value'

    # overriding the class variable
    LineHighChart.chart_title = 'new Class Variable'

    print('class variable:        {}'.format(LineHighChart.chart_title))

    # dict does not contain class variables
    print('highchart.__dict__:    {}'.format(highchart.__dict__))

    # get the NEW object variable!
    print('highchart.chart_title: {}'.format(highchart.chart_title))
    # title uses the class variable 
    print('highchart.title:       {}'.format(highchart.title))
    # title2 uses the 'old' class variable
    print('highchart.title2:      {}'.format(highchart.title2))

    # get the class variable, because no new object variable was set
    print('lowchart.chart_title:  {}'.format(lowchart.chart_title))
    # title uses the class variable 
    print('lowchart.title:        {}'.format(lowchart.title))
    # title2 uses the 'old' class variable
    print('lowchart.title2:       {}'.format(lowchart.title2))

weight_graph(None)
```

And the output is:

```
class variable:        new Class Variable
highchart.__dict__:    {'title2': {'x': -20, 'text': 'Class Variable'}, 'chart_title': 'new object variable value'}

highchart.chart_title: new object variable value
highchart.title:       {'x': -20, 'text': 'new Class Variable'}
highchart.title2:      {'x': -20, 'text': 'Class Variable'}

lowchart.chart_title:  new Class Variable
lowchart.title:        {'x': -20, 'text': 'new Class Variable'}
lowchart.title2:       {'x': -20, 'text': 'Class Variable'}
```